# How can I create a rounded rectangular border for GridView on Android?

Tags: android

I want to create a rounded rectangular border for GridView on Android like the below image:

[image: GridView]

How can i achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: just create a shape in xml and set the shape in background of layout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

create a drawable shape as follow and set as background to your view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#C0C0C0"></solid>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000"></stroke>
    <corners android:radius="5dp"></corners>

</shape>
```

P.S. this will only create a round-corner rectangle

Answer (score 4):

The idea is to first create a shape drawable that has rounded edges and colors you like. Here's an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<gradient 
    android:startColor="#353535"
    android:endColor="#222222"
    android:angle="90" />

<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#404040"/>

<corners android:radius="10dp" />

<padding 
    android:left="10dp" 
    android:top="10dp"
    android:right="10dp" 
    android:bottom="10dp" />

</shape>
```

Then set this as the background of your `GridView` using `android:background`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create [shape-drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) and set it as background for your GridView either by xml `android:background` attribute or in Java code via `setBackgroundResource()`

Answer (score 1):

you could achieve it in 3 simple steps :

STEP 1: 
I created a shape as Rectangle as below :

```
<stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#FF00FF00" />

<solid android:color="#ffffff" />
<padding android:left="7dp" android:top="7dp"
        android:right="7dp" android:bottom="7dp" />
<corners android:radius="4dp" />
```

STEP 2: 
Store this XML in Res/Drawable folder .xml

STEP 3: 
now Refer this shape in your code as GridView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawble..xml).

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
  Rect rHole = new Rect(pTopLeft.x, pTopLeft.y, pBotRight.x, pBotRight.y);
```

or

```
 canvas.drawRect(30,0,35,50,Reference_to_Paint_Object);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this to create shape ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient android:startColor="#CBCBCA" android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:angle="270" />
        <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
            android:topRightRadius="7dp" />
    </shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:endColor="#ffffff"
        android:startColor="#ffffff" />

    <corners android:radius="8dp" />

</shape>

SUe it In background of parent layout. it will help you.
```