# In Android Programming, How to make a GridView in Java without using XML?

Tags: java, android, gridview

I want to make a **GridView** in java, I don't want to use an XML. The example below is an XML as a Layout. It shows 3 columns. I want to achieve that setting using Java only.

In my Activity, instead of `GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById (R.id.gridview);`

I use `GridView gv = new GridView (this);`.

Now my only **problem** is that **it has only 1 column**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "I dont want to use an XML" -- why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code equivalent to `android:numColumns` is `setNumColumns(int)`. For things like id you'll need to go back to View docs. Width and height will be set with LayoutParams .

[GridView Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android%3acolumnWidth) on Android Developer.Com

Comment: Do you have an Idea on how can I add Border in the pictures in my GridView?

Answer (score 2):

Try This.

```
GridView gv = new GridView(context);
gv.setId(999999);
gv.setLayoutParams(new    
GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
gv.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
gv.setNumColumns(3);
gv.setColumnWidth(GridView.AUTO_FIT);
gv.setVerticalSpacing(5);
gv.setHorizontalSpacing(5);
gv.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH);
gv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Comment: Do you have an Idea on How to add borders in my pictures in Gridview?

Comment: you can refer the below link for apply border on pictures in gridview(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910129/how-can-i-create-a-rounded-rectangular-border-for-gridview-on-android)